# Why does my connection drop when the client doesn't send any more data?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

So I have a server which accepts incoming connections and then grabs the `TcpClient` in order to get the stream so that data can be send and received though that stream.

As for right now I'm only trying to read the data, and it works perfectly! The only issue is that, if I send data as the client to the server, the server then interprets the data just as it should, it reads every single bit just the way it's intended. But if the packet doesnt send anymore data within the next 50 - 60 seconds, the server throws this exception

***Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..***

As soon as the client is connected the server enters a loop and starts reading data like so

```
while (isConnected)
{
    var packetOpCode = nr.ReadByte();
    var packetSize = Constants.INCOMING_SIZES[packetOpCode];
    NetPacket packet;

        /* i.e 127 */
        packetSize = nr.ReadByte();
        var payload = nr.ReadBytes(packetSize);
        packet = new NetPacket
        {
            OpCode = packetOpCode,
            Length = packetSize,
            Payload = payload
        };
    
    _packets.Add(packet);
    /* If anything here crashes, then treat it as a faulty packet and disconnect the user. */
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"#: {_id} Queue: [{_packets.Count}] - Packet with ID: {packet.OpCode} added. ");
    File.AppendAllText("Log.txt",
        $"#: {_id} Queue: [{_packets.Count}] - Packet with ID: {packet.OpCode} added. \n");
}
```

where `nr` is a instance of my `NetReader` class

```
public class NetReader : BinaryReader
{
    private readonly NetworkStream _ns;
    public NetReader(NetworkStream ns) : base(ns)
    {
        _ns = ns;
        base.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
    }
}
```

And all I'm doing on the client is

- Connect To Server
- Create a byte[] and send it through that connection by doing `Client.Send(..);`

So it's only sending one packet and then it's idling, the application doesn't exit or anything, it just doesn't send anymore data.

```
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", portNumber);
PacketBuilder builder = new PacketBuilder();
builder.AddOpCode(4);
builder.AddByte(4);
builder.AddString("Test");
var packet = builder.GetByteArray();
client.Client.Send(packet, packet.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

The packet looks like this `4 4 54 65 73 74`

Since the server is looping, trying to read more data once it's read the first packet, the second iteration it will get stuck on this line `var packetOpCode = nr.ReadByte();` since it's a blocking call.

It's almost as if there is a timeout somewhere, but I can't figure out what making the connection drop.

Why am I getting the exception on the server? Is there a hidden timeout somewhere?

Comment: I'm not a C#-er, but I'd imagine TcpClient has a way to set TCP keep-alives and tune its parameters.

Comment: Looks like [TcpClient.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client?view=net-5.0) returns the underlying socket that has a [SetSocketOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption?view=net-5.0) method you could use to configure [TCP keep-alives.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive)

Comment: The `TcpClient` has both a `SendTimeout` and `ReceiveTimeout` which can be set. If I remember correctly the default timeout is 1 minute.

Comment: @Rafael Possibly, I feel like it might have something to do with how tcp works and how there is suppose to be an ACK etc, I'm far from being well educated when it comes to TCP so I could be wrong.

Comment: @WBuck If you could find any documentation on the default timeout that would be amazing!

Comment: `var client = new TcpClient( ) { SendTimeout = 1000, ReceiveTimeout = 1000 };` That 1 minute default is `Windows` specific I think.

Comment: @WBuck I started thinking about that being an option too! I wonder where I could find more documentation about it though.

Comment: Seems like the issue had something to do with the fact that the client was made in WPF, and I believe it loses it's context, dumping the connection that way because I'm not seeing the same issue using a console application as the client. I'll update this with an actual answer as soon as I figure out exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not timeout, unless its implementation specifically implements a timeout.

An established TCP connection that doesn't send any data for 100 years is still an established TCP connection.

So long as each end still exists, there is no reason for either end to send a packet to the other, they can each just sit there waiting FOREVER.

So:

1. Servers and/or Clients can close idle connections to free up resources.
2. Firewalls and NAT devices can expunge state information so that your connection no longer works when you come to use it again.
3. Firewalls and NAT devices can also fake close an idle tcp connection, by sending a RST to the client or server.

From what you have explained, it sounds like the server is closing the connection because it has not seen any data, thus it is freeing resources.

Check your server implementation.